# Flutter Camera display recording video duration

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to display video recording duration while continue video recording with [flutter camera plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/camera). However plugin has not any event listener or another method to attach start and stop video record events. I can calculate duration when user pressed start record and stop record buttons but I look more precision solution.

Answer (score 3):

Check this

UI Display camera with duration
[image]

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _stopwatch = Stopwatch();
  }

body: Expanded(
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.black,
                border: Border.all(
                  color:
                  controller != null && controller!.value.isRecordingVideo
                      ? Colors.redAccent
                      : Colors.grey,
                  width: 3.0,
                ),
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Center(
                      child: _cameraPreviewWidget(),
                    ),
                    Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                        child: Text(formatTime(_stopwatch.elapsedMilliseconds), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 48.0,color: Colors.red))),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

add timer function when the video started or Paused time

```
late Stopwatch _stopwatch;



void handleStartStop() {
    if (_stopwatch.isRunning) {
      _stopwatch.stop();
    } else {
      _stopwatch.start();
      // _stopwatch.reset();
    }
    setState(() {});    // re-render the page
  }
```

reset timer when video stoped call this function

```
void timerReset() {
    if (_stopwatch.isRunning) {
      setState(() {
        _stopwatch.reset();
      });  
    }
  }
```

// Start video

```
 void onVideoRecordButtonPressed() {
    startVideoRecording().then((value) {
      handleStartStop();
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

// Resume video

```
void onResumeButtonPressed() {
    resumeVideoRecording().then((_) {
     handleStartStop();
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {});
      }
     showInSnackBar('Video recording resumed');
    });
  }
```

// stop video func

```
void onStopButtonPressed() {
    stopVideoRecording().then((XFile? file) {
      timerReset();
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {});
      }
      if (file != null) {
        showInSnackBar('Video recorded to ${file.path}');
        videoFile = file;
        _startVideoPlayer();
      }
    });
  }
```